# Why is the ability to edit freely based on reputation?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Having edits appear immediately requires a certain reputation. However, most of the edits I suggest get approved. Wouldn't it be better to have this privilege be based on edit quality rather than reputation? Something like, edits you make become public immediately after you have made 20 approved edits?

Comment: Only 20? That would be far to easy to exploit. I don't think you thought this request through, it seems more like a micro rant thant than a constructive disscussion. How about making it 1000 edits?

Comment: I don't think it's that easy to get 20 edits that each require manual approval by someone with a high enough reputation

Comment: It's extremely easy to get 20 edits approved. Correct typos and grammar in 20 posts. Or add link sources to them. Or fix formatting... There are a lot of ways.

Comment: @MarkKirby if you solely do edits on questions and answers it would need you in fact to make 1000 of them to get to 2000 reputation. So you are close :)

Comment: @Videonauth You can only get [1000 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/259230) from suggested edits. Nothing more.

Comment: @KazWolfe good never needed that many edit suggestions tho :D

Answer (score 7):

The reason this is based on reputation is because reputation indicates *general trust* on the network. Editing is one of the most fundamental (and dangerous) powers on this site. Upon reaching the 2000 rep threshold, you would have the ability to change *any* post on the site however you want.

Assuming you don't have any reputation cap overages, this means you would have had to spend ***ten days, and reach the maximum daily reputation on each one of those days,*** on the site before earning this privilege. In those ten days of extreme activity, it's believed that you reasonably know what a good post looks like, and how to make them.

Twenty edits is nothing. If we gave this power to anyone with only 20 edits, they can make changes that would potentially go undiscovered for a long time. Forcing people through the queue until they reach this point makes sure that they know what they're doing, and that we as a community can push editors in the right direction so that they will be able to work effectively once they hit the 2000 rep mark.

According to your own account, the four months you've been here has resulted in 31 edit suggestions from your account. 25 of those were accepted and 6 were rejected.

Just today, we've had a total of 55 edits come through the review queue. Someone can do twenty edits in a period of a few hours provided they've tried.

Comment: Well, technically you can earn four 500-rep bounties on your first day! ;) (Or is there any protocol which will prevent that from happening?)

Comment: @terdon Thanks for cleaning up after my coffee-deprived mind. :P

Answer (score 3):

20 approved edits is IMO a far to low threshold. This reputation system is designed so you have to be on the site for a while to gain rights to do that. And 20 approved edits you could achieve in under a day if you're keen for it.

And then having this right would simply give you the ability to deface questions/answers.

Sure this might get caught quick but to prevent that the system is designed as it is, having different hurdles to bring you slowly into moderation of the site.